# Spring Security Webflux/Reactive Exception Handling

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm building app on spring webflux, and i'm stuck because spring security webflux (v.M5) did not behave like Spring 4 in term of exception handling.

I saw following post about how to customise spring security webflux:
[Spring webflux custom authentication for API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354171/spring-webflux-custom-authentication-for-api)

If we throw exception let say in ServerSecurityContextRepository.load, Spring will update http header to 500 and nothing i can do to manipulate this exception.

However, any error thrown in controller can be handled using regular @ControllerAdvice, it just spring webflux security.

Is there anyway to handle exception in spring webflux security?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution I found is creating a component implementing `ErrorWebExceptionHandler`. The instances of `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` bean run before Spring Security filters. Here's a sample that I use:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class GlobalExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {

  @Autowired
  private DataBufferWriter bufferWriter;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    AppError appError = ErrorCode.GENERIC.toAppError();

    if (ex instanceof AppException) {
        AppException ae = (AppException) ex;
        status = ae.getStatusCode();
        appError = new AppError(ae.getCode(), ae.getText());

        log.debug(appError.toString());
    } else {
        log.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    if (exchange.getResponse().isCommitted()) {
        return Mono.error(ex);
    }

    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(status);
    return bufferWriter.write(exchange.getResponse(), appError);
  }
}
```

If you're injecting the `HttpHandler` instead, then it's a bit different but the idea is the same.

**UPDATE:** For completeness, here's my `DataBufferWriter` object, which is a `@Component`:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Slf4j
public class DataBufferWriter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public <T> Mono<Void> write(ServerHttpResponse httpResponse, T object) {
        return httpResponse
            .writeWith(Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
                DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = httpResponse.bufferFactory();
                try {
                    return bufferFactory.wrap(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(object));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.warn("Error writing response", ex);
                    return bufferFactory.wrap(new byte[0]);
                }
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you get the DataBufferWritter in this case?

Comment: httpResponse.writeWith was the only variant that worked for me, allowing to customize message on configuration level.

Comment: this is the correct answer, you can find a complete example code in https://github.com/eriknyk/webflux-jwt-security-demo

Comment: I tried that and here is the CORS error I am getting:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8084/users/files' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to register any bean and change default Spring behavior. Try more elegant solution instead:

**We have:**

1. The custom implementation of the ServerSecurityContextRepository
2. The method .load return Mono

   ```
   public class HttpRequestHeaderSecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {
       ....
       @Override
       public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
           List<String> tokens = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("X-Auth-Token");
           String token = (tokens != null && !tokens.isEmpty()) ? tokens.get(0) : null;

           Mono<Authentication> authMono = reactiveAuthenticationManager
                   .authenticate( new HttpRequestHeaderToken(token) );

           return authMono
                   .map( auth -> (SecurityContext)new SecurityContextImpl(auth))
       }
   ```

   }

**The problem is:** if the `authMono` will contains an `error` instead of `Authentication` - spring will return the http response with *500* status (which means "an unknown internal error") instead of *401*. Even the error is AuthenticationException or it's subclass - it makes no sense - Spring will return 500.

But it is clear for us: an AuthenticationException should produce the 401 error...

To solve the problem we have to help Spring how to convert an Exception into the HTTP response status code.

To make it we have can just use the appropriate Exception class: `ResponseStatusException` or just map an original exception to this one (for instance, by adding the `onErrorMap()` to the `authMono` object). See the final code:

```
    public class HttpRequestHeaderSecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {
        ....
        @Override
        public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
            List<String> tokens = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("X-Auth-Token");
            String token = (tokens != null && !tokens.isEmpty()) ? tokens.get(0) : null;

            Mono<Authentication> authMono = reactiveAuthenticationManager
                    .authenticate( new HttpRequestHeaderToken(token) );

            return authMono
                    .map( auth -> (SecurityContext)new SecurityContextImpl(auth))
                    .onErrorMap(
                            er -> er instanceof AuthenticationException,
                            autEx -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, autEx.getMessage(), autEx)
                    )
                ;
            )
        }
   }
```

Comment: this solution is not working

Answer (score 5):

I just went trough lots of documentation, having a similar problem.

My solution was using ResponseStatusException.  AccessException of Spring-security  seems to be understood.

```
.doOnError(
          t -> AccessDeniedException.class.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass()),
          t -> AUDIT.error("Error {} {}, tried to access {}", t.getMessage(), principal, exchange.getRequest().getURI())) // if an error happens in the stream, show its message
.onErrorMap(
        SomeOtherException.class, 
        t -> { return new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,  "Collection not found");})
      ;
```

If this goes in the right direction for you, I can provide a bit better sample.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution and works like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: How do you map any generic exception without relying in ControllerAdvice? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-errors I was trying this one but it does not work with spring boot webflux 2.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: Sorry, don't know, but I think that's worth another question...