# Throw an exception in a WebFilter class and handle it in a ControllerAdvice class

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm trying to implement a `WebFilter` that checks a JWT and throw an exception if the check fails or the result is not valid. And I've a `@ControllerAdvice` class that handles those exceptions. But it doesn't work.

#### This is the `WebFilter` class:

```
@Component
public class OktaAccessTokenFilter implements WebFilter {

private JwtVerifier jwtVerifier;

   @Autowired
   public OktaAccessTokenFilter(JwtVerifier jwtVerifier) {
        this.jwtVerifier = jwtVerifier;
   }

   @Override
   public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization"))
            .flatMap(list -> list.stream().findFirst())
            .filter(authHeader -> !authHeader.isEmpty() && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
            .map(authHeader -> authHeader.replaceFirst("^Bearer", ""))
            .map(jwtString -> {
                try {
                    jwtVerifier.decodeAccessToken(jwtString);
                } catch (JoseException e) {
                    throw new DecodeAccessTokenException();
                }
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new AuthorizationException());
      }
}
```

#### And the exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class SecurityExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(AuthorizationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity authorizationExceptionHandler(AuthorizationException ex) {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();

  }

  @ExceptionHandler(DecodeAccessTokenException.class)
  public ResponseEntity decodeAccessTokenExceptionHandler(DecodeAccessTokenException ex) {

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();

  }

}
```

I think, the `@ControllerAdvice` class can not handle exceptions that `WebFilter` throws. Because, if I move the exceptions to the controller, it works.

#### I've change the code for this (for now):

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    Optional<String> authJwt = Optional.ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization"))
            .flatMap(list -> list.stream().findFirst())
            .filter(authHeader -> !authHeader.isEmpty() && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
            .map(authHeader -> authHeader.replaceFirst("^Bearer", ""));

    if (authJwt.isPresent()) {
        String jwtString = authJwt.get();
        try {
            jwtVerifier.decodeAccessToken(jwtString);
        } catch (JoseException e) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.empty());
        }
    } else {
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.empty());
    }

    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

What do you think about the problem? Do you know another way to implement it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try defining an `@Order()` for both your `@ControllerAdvice` and `@WebFilter` beans, and giving `@ControllerAdvice` higher precedence.

However, I don't think that's the way to go, main reason being the `@ControllerAdvice` exception handlers don't return reactive types. Instead, I would define a bean which implements `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` instead. This handler is added to reactive flow by `spring-webflux, so you don't need to worry about the precedence. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958622/spring-security-webflux-reactive-exception-handling/49446038#49446038) for details.

Comment: Thanks ! I implemented the second approach and It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in webflux, you do not want to throw a direct exception or return a mono error in the webfilter), however you want to set the response to be the mono error containing the exception (Close to what you have done). This will allow the exception to be thrown in the correct part of the requests workflow and hence it will bubble up to your rest Controller advice

```
public class YourFilter implements WebFilter{

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, final WebFilterChain chain){
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.error(new YouException()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that and I have a CORS error
Here is the error:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8084/users/files' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Where you able to fix your cors issue ? I am experimenting the same issue. Thanks