# Can I implement WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter on Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm currently using Springs' WebFlux and I wanted to implement Spring Security. I am struggling to make any of my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` http rules work and I am thinking it is because `HttpSecurity` changes have no effect. I'll explain what I mean:

I have chosen to implement `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which has the method signature.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
```

This has been correctly configured but all of my endpoints receive `401` unauthorized (which is typical of a Configuration not being picked up and a default configuration being used instead). Instead, when I look at the implementations for WebFluxSecurity they usually implement a Bean with the following signature:

```
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(
  ServerHttpSecurity http)
```

I know a lot of the WebFlux architecture implements a different set of Requests and Response objects to typical Spring so I am wondering whether I have to implement the `WebFlux` security way of doing things or if the more standard `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` way of implementing security should still work

Cheers

Comment: Have you seen this for starters? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354171/spring-webflux-custom-authentication-for-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring webflux custom authentication for API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354171/spring-webflux-custom-authentication-for-api)

Answer (score 8):

`WebFluxSecurity` use `ServerHttpSecurity` that use `WebFilter` to filter request.
`WebSecurity` use `HttpSecurity` that `javax.servlet.Filter` to filter request.

it's different class and different implementation, overwrite:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
```

won't work