# Can anyone suggest how to validate (coming from realiable source,not expired) JWT token coming in header in spring webflux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive, boot

Can anyone suggest how to validate (coming from realiable source,not expired) JWT token coming in header in spring boot webflux.

Comment: https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ServerSecurityContextRepository` and override `Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange)` method.
Then extract the token from `ServerWebExchange` and perform validation.

And to use custom security context do:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BaseSecurityConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    protected final ServerSecurityContextRepository serverSecurityContextRepository;

    protected ServerHttpSecurity basicSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.securityContextRepository(serverSecurityContextRepository)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Vertigo I am very new to security part could you please help me with code that would be great help.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354171/spring-webflux-custom-authentication-for-api There are several approaches to it and custom ServerSecurityContextRepository is one of them ;)