# Spring webflux custom authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to have custom authentication using spring security using spring webflux .

I have two type authentication with different headers.

One of authentications use `x-user-id` and `x-forward-host`if it has acceptable value authentication will be successful .

Another way is having jwt token if Authorization header is acceptable authentication will be successful .

If user have Authorization header every thing is fine but if user try to use another way this error occurer:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
> com.zarebin.browser.edge.configuration.MyAuthentication to
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3889) ~[na:na]
> Suppressed:
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:  Error has
> been observed at the following site(s):   *__checkpoint ⇢
> com.zarebin.browser.edge.filters.BlockListFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢
> org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢ AuthorizationWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢ ExceptionTranslationWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerRequestCacheWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢
> SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> *__checkpoint ⇢ ReactorContextWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> *__checkpoint ⇢ HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> *__checkpoint ⇢ ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢
> org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢
> com.zarebin.browser.edge.filters.LogFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
> *__checkpoint ⇢
> org.springframework.web.filter.reactive.ServerHttpObservationFilter
> [DefaultWebFilterChain]   *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/profile"
> [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Original Stack Trace:       at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3889) ~[na:na]      at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:283)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:259)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:163)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.subscribe(MonoContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:44)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:503)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:258)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:245)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:305)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:224)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:295)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:411)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:360)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:291)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2025)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:265)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:305)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2545)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:191)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:117)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:87)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:206)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:274)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:887)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeekFuseable.java:940)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:85)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2547)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:847)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:609)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:589)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(FluxFlatMap.java:347)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:783)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2305)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:338)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:437)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2341)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2215)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxPeekFuseable.java:471)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2025)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDeferContextual.subscribe(MonoDeferContextual.java:55)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1840)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> io.micrometer.context.ContextSnapshot.lambda$wrap$0(ContextSnapshot.java:78)
> ~[context-propagation-1.0.2.jar:1.0.2]        at
> reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
> ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]       at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
> ~[na:na]      at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
> ~[na:na]      at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
> ~[na:na]      at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
> ~[na:na]      at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
> ~[na:na]      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

It try to cast `myAuthentication` to `JwtAuthenticationToken` but I do not want to convert

My Security Context Repository converter is :

```
@Override
    public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange exchange) {    
var forwardHost = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("X-Forwarded-Host");
        var userId = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("X-User-Id");
        Authentication authentication;
        var isForwardedPublic = forwardHost != null && forwardHost.equals("myhost.com");
        var auth = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");
        if (userId != null && isForwardedPublic) {
            authentication = new MyAuthentication(userId, true);
            return Mono.just(new SecurityContextImpl(authentication));
        } else if (!isForwardedPublic && auth != null) {

            NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder decoder = null;
            try {
                decoder = new NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder(new RSAKey.Builder(keys.pub()).build().toRSAPublicKey());
            } catch (JOSEException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return decoder.decode(auth.substring(7)).onErrorResume(e -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))).map(jwt -> {
                var jwtAuthenticationToken = new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt);
//                jwtAuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);
                return new SecurityContextImpl(jwtAuthenticationToken);
            });
```

my AuthenticationWebFilter:

```
  @Bean
    public AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter() {
        var filter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(publicAuthenticationManager());
        filter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(new ServerBodyAuthenticationConverter(keys));
        return filter;
    }
```

SecurityConfig:

```
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,
                                               SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {

        return http
                .logout().disable()
                .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .addFilterAfter(authenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.REACTOR_CONTEXT)
//                .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> getAuthorizeExchangeSpec(exchanges)
                        .pathMatchers(NOTIFICATION + "/client").denyAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated())
                .build();
    }
```

My AuthenticationManager:

```
@Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager publicAuthenticationManager() {
        return authentication -> {
            if (authentication instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken) {
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            }
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        };
    }
```

My customAuthentication:

```
@AllArgsCunstractor
class MyAuthentication implements Authentication{
  private String principal;
  private String authenticated;
}
```

I try to solve problem base on this issue [Spring webflux custom authentication for API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47354171/spring-webflux-custom-authentication-for-api) But I still have error

I even try to solve issue base of this article in [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authenticationmanagerresolver) But not work.

Comment: first of all why are you not showing us `MyAuthentication` second of all, if i just send a `X-User-Id` with a value, i get logged in, that is NOT security. This implementation looks super strange, and custom, and writing custom security is bad practice. So stop doing it.

Comment: As I said if X-User-Id dosent have aceptable value authentication will be failed . I add MyAuthentication .

Comment: we need to full log, we have no idea where the casting is beeing performed because you have just posted a single exception.

Comment: I add full log .